# Improve SimpleMembership query performance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t-sql, simplemembership

I have a sample database with 8 million users where the manage account page takes 8 seconds to render. It boils down to the method GetUserId calling Membership GetUser.

The GetUser sql looks like this:

```
SELECT [UserId] FROM [Users] WHERE (UPPER([UserName]) = @0)
```

When I run the following questions in the query analyzer I get the following results

```
SELECT [UserId] FROM [Users] WHERE [UserName] = 'CARL'
-- This question takes 11 milliseconds on my dev machine

SELECT [UserId] FROM [Users] WHERE UPPER([UserName]) = 'CARL'
-- This question takes 3.5 seconds on my dev machine
```

The UserName column has the following index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Users_UserName ON dbo.Users (UserName)
```

Can the sql query be changed? Can the query performance be improved in any other way?

Comment: This exact behavior is turning out to be 45% of our wait time and load. We are scaling up users and 3x active users now = 3x the wait and resources chewed up. response has gone form 1 second to 3 as user-ship increases with only 650,326 users in the database... I'm exploring using Identity to replace SimpleMembership asap

Comment: @Hunter It's easy to change the source and run a custom build. That's what I did.

Comment: Thanks! I found this tonight on my own as well! They are makign everything open source, this has to be too! When I last looked it was before all these new initiatives at MS. But in the end to touch the least amount of code. I ran this gem right here. And man it is NIGHT and day... I'm going to add it as an answer.
http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/11/improve-performance-by-optimizing-queries-for-asp-net-identity-and-other-membership-providers.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can the sql query be changed?

No, the SQL query is burnt into the code of the simple membership provider. Checkout with reflector the code of the `WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.GetUserId` method which looks like this:

```
internal static int GetUserId(IDatabase db, string userTableName, string userNameColumn, string userIdColumn, string userName)
{
    object obj2 = db.QueryValue("SELECT " + userIdColumn + " FROM " + userTableName + " WHERE (UPPER(" + userNameColumn + ") = @0)", new object[] { userName.ToUpperInvariant() });
    if (<GetUserId>o__SiteContainer5.<>p__Site6 == null)
    {
        <GetUserId>o__SiteContainer5.<>p__Site6 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, bool>>.Create(Binder.UnaryOperation(CSharpBinderFlags.None, ExpressionType.IsTrue, typeof(SimpleMembershipProvider), new CSharpArgumentInfo[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) }));
    }
    if (<GetUserId>o__SiteContainer5.<>p__Site7 == null)
    {
        <GetUserId>o__SiteContainer5.<>p__Site7 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>.Create(Binder.BinaryOperation(CSharpBinderFlags.None, ExpressionType.NotEqual, typeof(SimpleMembershipProvider), new CSharpArgumentInfo[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null), CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.Constant, null) }));
    }
    if (!<GetUserId>o__SiteContainer5.<>p__Site6.Target(<GetUserId>o__SiteContainer5.<>p__Site6, <GetUserId>o__SiteContainer5.<>p__Site7.Target(<GetUserId>o__SiteContainer5.<>p__Site7, obj2, null)))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (<GetUserId>o__SiteContainer5.<>p__Site8 == null)
    {
        <GetUserId>o__SiteContainer5.<>p__Site8 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, int>>.Create(Binder.Convert(CSharpBinderFlags.ConvertExplicit, typeof(int), typeof(SimpleMembershipProvider)));
    }
    return <GetUserId>o__SiteContainer5.<>p__Site8.Target(<GetUserId>o__SiteContainer5.<>p__Site8, obj2);
}
```

You will have to write a custom membership provider if you want to change this behavior.

Comment: And it's an internal static method... That's unfortunate.

Comment: Yeap, *internal static*, my favorite combination of access modifiers in a class which I don't have access to the source code :-)

Comment: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs
It seems like a custom build is feasible.

Comment: I think carl's right in the long run. But if you're in a bit of a pickle as I was and only had access to read the code and full access to the DB in operation see the answer I gave here.

Answer (score 1):

As per MS recommendation run the following SQL to improve your performance:

TIL while trying to solve this same problem. The call to UPPER does not use the index.

Try this in the short term if you can afford the resource:

```
ALTER TABLE Users ADD NormalizedName  AS UPPER(UserName);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NormalizedName] ON [Users] ([NormalizedName] ASC);
```

After doing this I got very reasonable performance out of simple membership (enough to last me till I replace it with identity or the next best thing.)

http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/11/improve-performance-by-optimizing-queries-for-asp-net-identity-and-other-membership-providers.aspx

And modify the code yourself in the long run and replace the compiled version. Carl R pointed out this project is now open source too. So now you can rewrite it to taste.
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs